# MYSQL - Join three tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have this database :

```
Image : id,user_id,[..],created_at
Visit : id,image_id,created_at
user : id,[..]
```

and I have this query to get the top uploader users ,

```
$current_month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first day of this month")) . ' 23:59:59';
$users = DB::query("SELECT * ,
      COUNT(p.id) as numPics
    FROM
      images p 
    INNER JOIN
      users u
    ON
     p.user_id = u.id
   WHERE 
     p.created_at >= \"$current_month\"
   GROUP BY p.user_id
   ORDER BY numPics DESC LIMIT 10");
```

What I have is to joing the visit table so I can get the total vists of each image IN THE CURRENT MONTH.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406703/joing-three-tables-on-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of your visit table, I can't give specific details, but you should be able to add a `JOIN` clause for visit after the `JOIN` for users:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(p.id) as numPics, COUNT(v.id) as numVisits
FROM images p 
INNER JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN visits v ON v.image_id = p.id AND v.created_at >= "$current_month"
WHERE p.created_at >= "$current_month"
GROUP BY p.user_id
ORDER BY numPics DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: it doesn't wroks especially the where clause !

Comment: Right, as I noted, without knowing the structure of the visit table, I can only guess what the column names and types are. You'll have to modify the example to suit your situation.

Comment: i posted my database structure dear you can re-read the question .

Comment: @Hamza I don't see your database structure anywhere in the post, I just re-read it.

Comment: Updated query to match your DB structure, though without knowing exactly how your columns are used, it's still just a guess. You may have to do some work on your own to fit this example to your situation.

Comment: You'll have to do some of your own work to make it fit. I suggest checking out the extensive documentation on the MySQL website if you need to learn more about crafting SQL queries: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index.html

Comment: the problem dear Adrian is i don't have any idea about the problem!

Comment: @Hamza we have no more information than you do; you'll have to do some trial and error and troubleshooting. Such is the nature of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an image_id field on the visits table:

```
SELECT * ,
  COUNT(p.id) as numPics
FROM
  images p 
INNER JOIN
  users u
ON
  p.user_id = u.id

    INNER JOIN visits as v ON v.image_id = p.id

 WHERE 
 p.created_at >= \"$current_month\"
GROUP BY p.user_id
ORDER BY numPics DESC LIMIT 10"
```

Comment: the same trouble it doesn't filter the photo of the current month it retun all photos!